# PHP preg_replace - remove BR tags between ul, li tags

Tags: php

I would like to create a regex which will be strip all BR tags between ul/ol li tags. For example:

```
Test<br>
<ul>
<li>
Test<br>
</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to get this result:

```
Test<br>
<ul>
<li>
Test
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using this code:

```
    $param_array['description'] = preg_replace('/(?<=<ul>|<\/li>)([\s*<br>\s*|\s*<br\/>\s*|\s*<br \/>\s*]+)(?=<\/ul>|<li>)/is', "$1$3", $param_array['description']);
    $param_array['description'] = preg_replace('/(?<=<ol>|<\/li>)([\s*<br>\s*|\s*<br\/>\s*|\s*<br \/>\s*]+)(?=<\/ol>|<li>)/is', "$1$3", $param_array['description']);
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Use the str_replace() function to remove any instances of 
 :)

```
<?php 
    $html = "Test<br>
    <ul>
    <li>
    Test<br>
    </li>
    </ul>";

    $without_breaks = str_replace(array('<br>', '&', '"'), ' ', $html);

?>
```

Comment: Your code will remove all BR tags from all my code. I want strip BR tags only BETWEEN UL/OL tags, so: `<ul><li>HERE_I_WANT_REMOVE_BR_TAGS</li></ul> BUT HERE I WANT ALLOW BR TAGS <br><br><br>`

Comment: <?php 
    $html1 = "Test<br>";
    $html2 = "
    <ul>
    <li>
    Test<br>
    </li>
    </ul>";

    $without_breaks = str_replace(array('<br>', '&', '"'), ' ', $html2);

    $finalhtml = $html1 . $without_breaks;
    echo $finalhtml;
?>

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using CSS:
li br {display:none;}

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = preg_replace_callback(
                        '~<ul>.*?</ul>~s', //match between <ul>s
                        function ($matches) {
                            return preg_replace('~<br.*?>~', '', $matches[0]); //strip all  <br>
                        },
                        $html 
                );
```

So the preg replace call back grabs everything between the ul tags and then passes it to the preg replace which strips the br tags

sorry for the late answer but I was trying to do the same thing and came across this.